# Update column value using group by another column value

Tags: mysql, row-number

I'm solving one problem for courier service, they have different routes and each route can have n-number of parcels. They are arranging 2 parcels in one bag. I managed to get data like:

```
Route  | ParcelId | GroupId |
-------|----------|---------
NORTH  | P1       |    1    | 
NORTH  | P2       |    1    |
NORTH  | P3       |    2    |
NORTH  | P4       |    2    |
NORTH  | P5       |    3    |
EAST   | P6       |    1    |
EAST   | P7       |    1    |
EAST   | P8       |    2    |
CENTRAL| P9       |    1    |
CENTRAL| P10      |    1    |
CENTRAL| P11      |    2    |
CENTRAL| P11      |    2    |
-------|----------|---------|
```

using below query:

```
select 
Route, ParcelId
    -- calculate the group number for every 2 parcels, increment 1
    ceiling(row_number() over(partition by route order by ParcelId) / 2.0) GroupId
from Parcel (nolock)
where
    ship_date = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Here Parcel P1,P2 from North route and P6, P7 from East route have same GroupId.
But I want unique identifier on Parcels based on Route i.e. instead of just 1/2/3.. if I could get N1, N2, N3 (For North route) and E1, E2 (For East route) it will be helpful for me while arranging Parcels inside bags.

So I want result set should look like:

```
Route  | ParcelId | GroupId |
-------|----------|---------
NORTH  | P1       |    N1   | 
NORTH  | P2       |    N1   |
NORTH  | P3       |    N2   |
NORTH  | P4       |    N2   |
NORTH  | P5       |    N3   |
EAST   | P6       |    E1   |
EAST   | P7       |    E1   |
EAST   | P8       |    E2   |
CENTRAL| P9       |    C1   |
CENTRAL| P10      |    C1   |
CENTRAL| P11      |    C2   |
CENTRAL| P11      |    C2   |
-------|----------|---------|
```

If not exactly N1/E1/C1.. identifier should be unique (based on route) and I need to update some empty field on Parcel table, so would be needing update script for the same.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks Sagar Gangwal for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
Route, ParcelId,CONCAT(CASE WHEN ROUTE='NORTH' THEN 'N' WHEN ROUTE='EAST' THEN 'E' WHEN ROUTE='WEST' THEN 'W' WHEN ROUTE='SOUTH' THEN 'S' WHEN ROUTE='CENTRAL' THEN 'C' END,GroupId) AS GroupId 
from Parcel 
where ship_date = cast(getdate() as date)
```

You can try above query.

Comment: Arrr! It was so simple and I wasted so much time in writing story! Thanks Sagar. You rock!